# Can't install Vagrant 1.0.4 with gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, vagrant

I'm trying to install Vagrant 1.0.4 with gem but it's not working for me and I can't think of a fix. I enter this prompt and I get the following message:

```
gem install vagrant -v 1.0.4
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing vagrant:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I am restricted to using Ruby 1.8.7 in this environment, and also Vagrant 1.0.4.

[The log is huge so I'm putting it on Pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/bhB3qqxx)

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: you can get some info from [here](https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom/issues/194)